# I can't get a FCM click action to work on IOS PWA

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

The notifications clicked work fine on both android (installed PWA) and chrome but in ios, I haven't had success, At the moment we set the "category" parameter in the payload and the additional actions on the notifications but I have not been able to perform a clicked when the notification is clicked.
Is there a way to send actionable notifications to iOS devices?

Sample JSON of message payload:

```
{
    "to": "cadyI6R8vE27vTOfjE157N:APA91bFIEkJqcHzHex9qOOB3eDGWnKg8Fv74iTgDcJDsUVha81hdtphy1fnPDa7rFlRcK48L8vJkthzOp3NyEd_cvSbOcJ4eI335K2N9I-E8ZfA85_2_OnP02OO8vfGv0Gxzz2ACtfSF",
    "collapse_key":"type_a",
    "notification":{
        "title":"Le Soir d\u2019Alg\u00e9rie",
        "body":"Justice : Le proc\u00e8s de Chakib Khelil pr\u00e9vu aujourd\u2019hui",
        "icon":"/images/favicon.png",
        "click_action":"https://www.lesoirdalgerie.com/actualites/les-graves-accusations-de-benbahmed-80545",
        "sound": "default"
    },
    "apns":{
        "payload":{
            "aps":{

                "category":"GENERAL"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my AppDelegatecode :

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseMessaging


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    var window : UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                       didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // TODO: if we're using Firebase, uncomment this
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        // [START set_messaging_delegate]
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        // [END set_messaging_delegate]
        // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
        // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
        // [START register_for_notifications]
   
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })


        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        
        Messaging.messaging().token { token, error in
          if let error = error {
            print("Error fetching FCM registration token: \(error)")
          } else if let token = token {
            print("FCM registration token: \(token)")
          }
        }
        
        let generalCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "GENERAL",
                                                     actions: [],
                                                     intentIdentifiers: [],
                                                     options: .customDismissAction)
         
        // Register the category.
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.setNotificationCategories([generalCategory])
        
        Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "allDevices") { error in
          print("Subscribed to weather topic")
        }


        // [END register_for_notifications]
        return true
      }

      // [START receive_message]
      func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
          print("Message ID 1: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print("push userInfo 1:", userInfo)
        print("TAB")
        sendPushToWebView(userInfo: userInfo)
      }

      func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                       fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
          print("Message ID 2: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message. **
        print("push userInfo 2:", userInfo)
        print("TAB")
        sendPushToWebView(userInfo: userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
      }

      // [END receive_message]
      func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }

      // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
      // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
      // the FCM registration token.
//      func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
//        print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")
//
//        // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
//        // Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
//      }
    }

    // [START ios_10_message_handling]
    extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

      func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                  willPresent notification: UNNotification,
        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
          print("Message ID: 3 \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print("push userInfo 3:", userInfo)
          print("ghiii");
          var json = "";
          do {
              let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: userInfo)
              json = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
              print(json);
              let t = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: Any];
              if let h = t?["category"] as! String? {
                  print(h);
                  if let url = URL(string: h) {
                      UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                  }
              }

          } catch {
              print("ERROR: userInfo parsing problem")
          }
        sendPushToWebView(userInfo: userInfo)

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([[.alert, .sound]])
      }

      func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                  didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                  withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
          print("Message ID 4: \(messageID)")
        }

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print full message.
        print("push userInfo 4:", userInfo)
        sendPushToWebView(userInfo: userInfo)

        completionHandler()
      }
    }
    // [END ios_10_message_handling]

    extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
      // [START refresh_token]
      func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")
        
        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
      }
      // [END refresh_token]
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated since I have not found a single thing that would help me understand this.